# How can I convert this working JAVASCRIPT code to JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


function hasPasswordChanged(value)
  {
        if(value == '1')
        {
            var container = document.getElementById("sNav");
            if(document.getElementsByTagName)
            {
               var hyperLinkList = container.getElementsByTagName("a");

               for(var currentLink in hyperLinkList)
               {
                    hyperLinkList[currentLink].disabled = true;
                    hyperLinkList[currentLink].onclick =function () { return false;}

               }

            }
        }
  }


  window.onload = function () 
  {
        hasPasswordChanged('<%  = HasPasswordAlreadyChanged %>');
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Given that jQuery *is* JavaScript, I'm having trouble not making the glib response and reposting your exact code as an answer.  :P

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  What jquery features do you need to use? What is your objective? ETC?

Comment: @Daniel: while all jQuery is Javascript, not all Javascript is jQuery.

Comment: I am just curious how elegent and compact code might be with JQUERY. Of course, this code is working fine --- does what it needs to be done; of course I have tested this code on any other browser beside IE . Thanks.

Comment: @Daniel - no offense intended.

Comment: If it ain't broke, don't fix it.  There's no logical reason to convert this to jQuery if it works as is.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming I'm correct in that you want to disable the nav links on the page if the password has already changed (1 is true).

```
$(function() {
   var changed = <%= HasPasswordAlreadyChanged %>;
   if (changed) {
      $('#sNav a').attr('disabled','disabled')
                  .click( function() { return false; } );
   }
});
```

Comment: > Selects immediate children... Meanwhile getElementsByTagName selects descendants of a parent node. Also, you can set disabled using the .attr function.

Small nitpicks, just thought i'd share.

Comment: yea you have, but is disabled a proper attribute in html?

Comment: @TStamper - not for an anchor -- perhaps, that's the reason for also adding a click handler that returns false -- for browsers that don't support disabling an anchor.

Answer (score 1):

```
function hasPasswordChanged(value)
  {
        if(value == '1')
        {
            $('#sNav a').attr('disabled', 'true').click(function(){ return false; });
        }
  }

$(function(){
    hasPasswordChanged('<%  = HasPasswordAlreadyChanged %>');
})
```

or a bit wierder:

```
$(function(){
    <%  = HasPasswordAlreadyChanged %> == 1 ? $('#sNav a').attr('disabled', 'true').click(function(){ return false; }) : ""; 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    if ('<%  = HasPasswordAlreadyChanged %>' == '1') {
      $("#sNav").find("a").attr("disabled","disabled").click(function(){return false;});
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming HasPasswordAlreadyChanged is either 0 or 1 (or flase/true)

```
jQuery(function($){
  !!<%= HasPasswordAlreadyChanged %> && $("#sNav a").attr("disabled",true).click(function(){return false;})
})
```

Also, does a disabled attribute on A element affect it in any way ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function hasPassWordChanged(value) {
  if (value == '1') {
    $("#sNav a").attr("disabled", true).click(function() {return false;});
  }
}

$(function() {
  hasPasswordChanged('<%  = HasPasswordAlreadyChanged %');
});
```

This selects all `a` tags that are children of the node with id `sNav`, sets all of their disabled attributes to true, and sets the specified returning false function to be called upon the click event.

The last part, a call to `$()` with the specified function, runs the function when the DOM is ready to be worked on, and is a synonym for `$(document).ready()` when passed a function. You can also substitute this with your `window.onload` setting, but the call to `$()` is more preferred with jQuery.

Comment: Thank you for solution along with very nice explanation. That is really kind of you!

Answer (score 0):

As your JavaScript is working, there is probably no value in converting it to jQuery at the risk of introducing any bugs.

The only thing I might consider is using jQuery's event-handling rather than explicitly using **window.onload** :

```
function hasPasswordChanged() {
    // unchanged
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    hasPasswordChanged('<%  = HasPasswordAlreadyChanged %>');
});
```